# How to properly move helper components into children components in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a component with a `v-card` in it which looks like this:

```html
<!-- CurrentFile.vue -->
<v-card color="primary">
    <v-card-title class="secondary--text text-wrap">Flashing title</v-card-title>
    <v-card-subtitle>
        <span class="secondary--text text-h6">A fancy subtitle</span>
    </v-card-subtitle>
    <v-card-text class="mt-n3">
        ...
    </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

While refactoring, I wanted to create a new component that would encapsulate both `v-card-title` and `v-card-subtitle` helper components, since they use the same text color.

```html
<!-- CurrentFile.vue -->
<v-card color="primary">
    <my-new-header textColor="secondary--text" title="Flashing title" subtitle="A fancy subtitle"/>
    <v-card-text class="mt-n3">
        ...
    </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

I went on to create this child component

```html
<!-- MyNewHeader.vue -->
<template>
    <span>
        <v-card-title class="text-wrap" :class="textColor">{{ title }}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-subtitle>
            <span class="text-h6" :class="textColor">{{ subtitle }}</span>
        </v-card-subtitle>
    </span>
</template>
```

#### Issue

With the inclusion of a `<span>` tag, the use of `v-card-title` and `v-card-subtitle` components is almost irrelevant. It seems to me that both containers lose their properties (margins and paddings).

Of course, it's logical, since it adds an undesired level of hierarchy. Once the child component is injected, the structure ends up looking like this:

```html
<v-card>
    <span>
        <v-card-title/>
        <v-card-subtitle>
            <span/>
        </v-card-subtitle>
    </span>
    <v-card-text/>
</v-card>
```

I would very much remove that `<span>` tag to avoid all these problems, but there must only be one element at the template root.

Is there another way of doing what I want to do that I'm missing? Or maybe is it overkill to want that many sub-components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 possible solutions for your issue:

1. Using fragments - https://github.com/privatenumber/vue-frag
2. Using `render` function instead of a component template - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html
3. Using CSS `display: contents` to effectively replace the wrapper with its content - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-box

Comment: Wow I didn't know a module like `vue-frag` existed, I feel like it's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the other solutions provided, I will come back to them if needed